# Liquibase - advantages of using createTable over CREATE TABLE

Tags: liquibase

In my current liquibase project I usually use plain SQL to create tables, because I believe it gives better control over the DDL syntax, and I can paste exactly what I modeled. Of course I'm losing the automatic rollback functionality, but except that - are there any other benefits of using createTable elements over plain SQL?
I thought it has some advantages when you switch to a different database server, but even in this case I would probably just create a different version of the SQL manually (again, for better control over the DDL syntax).

Comment: I think Liquibase main advantage is the ability to abstract from the database, using an agnostic representation in XML or YAML and, of course, being able to rollback changes (but, with limitations). Using just plain SQL is possible, but you lose this feature and you bind to a particular database. Switching it later (if needed) will require a lot of rework.